# Distributing a union of types for a class's generic type var into a union of specialized class types

Tags: python, generics, types, mypy

I am trying to understand how specialization of generic types interacts with unions.  In particular, if you have a class `Foo` generic in `[T, U]` and `Foo` has some member functions that can only work in multiple specialized cases of `U`, one would like the type signature to read `def op(self: Foo[T, type1 | type2 | ...]) -> rettype: ...` and then this function could be successfully called for any of `Foo[T, type1], Foo[T, type2], ...]`.  This does not seem to work; instead, you have to "distribute" the union into a bunch of single Foo types: `def op(self: Foo[T type1] | Foo[T, type1] | Foo[T, type2] | ...) -> rettype: ...`.  Not really a problem for me, but I just want to make sure this is expected and that there are not any other more elegant ways to express this.

Motivation: In our project, the `op` methods on `Foo` return other `Foo` instances with possibly different types, and to generate those instances may, depending on the particular `op`, require the calling `self: Foo` to have certain types (because the new `Foo` instance will depend on the creator for its entire life -- think of a linked list or connected nodes).  The reason for having all these ops on the same class is chaining is possible: foo1.op1().op2().op3()...In order to get the most out of the typing system, we would like to make sure that for a given instance of `Foo`, an error is raised if an attempt is made to use one of the `op` factories on it that are not compatible with its types for `[T, U]`.

**tl;dr** What does Python say about the relationship between `Foo[T, A | B | C]` and `Foo[T, A] | Foo[T, B] | Foo[T, C]` for `TypeVar`s `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and some class `Foo` generic in them?

Below I have a simple mock up of what I am trying to do.  My hope was that *op1* and *op2* would be equivalent; i.e., unions would be "factored out" as is done in *op2*.  Is that expected?

I presented the *op3* case because I expected the line `Foo(0, 1.0).op1()` to fail for the same reason as the other *op1* calls.  By adding anotehr type, `| str` in this case, all three fail.  What's going on here?

```
# (Python 3.10, Linux, mypy 1.1.1)

from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Generic, TypeVar, cast

import numpy as np


T = TypeVar("T")
U = TypeVar("U")


class Foo(Generic[T, U]):
    def __init__(self, x: T, y: U):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def op1(self: Foo[T, int | float]) -> float:
        return self.y * 2.5

    def op2(self: Foo[T, float] | Foo[T, int]) -> float:
        return self.y * 2.5

    def op3(self: Foo[T, int | float | str]) -> float:
        return cast(float, self.y) * 2.5
        
Foo(0, 1).op1()     # error: Invalid self argument "Foo[int, int]" to attribute function "op1" with type "Callable[[Foo[T, Union[int, float]]], float]"  [misc]
Foo(0, 1.0).op1()   # ok: But why is this passing?  Why does the same .op3() call below fail when just adding another type to the union?
Foo(0, "1").op1()   # error: Invalid self argument "Foo[int, str]" to attribute function "op1" with type "Callable[[Foo[T, Union[int, float]]], float]"  [misc]

Foo(0, 1).op2()     # ok
Foo(0, 1.0).op2()   # ok
Foo(0, "1").op2()   # error: Invalid self argument "Foo[int, str]" to attribute function "op2" with type "Callable[[Union[Foo[T, float], Foo[T, int]]], float]"  [misc]

Foo(0, 1).op3()     # error: Invalid self argument "Foo[int, int]" to attribute function "op3" with type "Callable[[Foo[T, Union[int, float, str]]], float]"  [misc]
Foo(0, 1.0).op3()   # error: Invalid self argument "Foo[int, float]" to attribute function "op3" with type "Callable[[Foo[T, Union[int, float, str]]], float]"  [misc]
Foo(0, "1").op3()   # error: Invalid self argument "Foo[int, str]" to attribute function "op3" with type "Callable[[Foo[T, Union[int, float, str]]], float]"  [misc]
```

Comment: you shouldn't by annotating the `self` argument, and definitely not annotating `self` arg differently on different methods of the same class

Comment: `Foo` instance will infer the generic types from the args you pass to `__init__`, alternatively as a generic class you can supply type args like `Foo[int, str](0, "1").op2()`

Comment: you can achieve the example in the question by just removing the `self` annotations and adding a restriction to the TypeVar e.g. https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=3ade2dd492a87a2d4c44c28b134bc303

Comment: _"we would like to make sure that for a given instance of Foo, an error is raised if an attempt is made to use one of the `op` factories on it that are not compatible with its types for `[T, U]`"_ ...I think this will need some runtime checks that mypy can reason about e.g. https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=3b35cb8eff7649203d1e69b4ddf9c731

Comment: Regarding annotating self, I have tried to use a generic self (or Self type), but run into issues with both (posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76708029/mypy-does-not-type-check-generic-self-when-used-in-methods-scope-but-does-when).

Taking some time to ponder the covar/contravar issue.  Thanks for the playground!