# Mypy does not type check generic self when used in method's scope, but does when used in caller's scope or for explicitly typed self

Tags: python, types, mypy, typechecking

I have a class that generates instances of itself, and some of those instances can only be constructed (via other external functions) if the calling instance has certain types.  To avoid typing self directly, I tried using a generic self.  The approach follows the examples in https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-methods-and-generic-self and related PEP 673.

However, I found that while mypy accurately reveals the correct type of self, it *does not* enforce type correctness when self is used in the method's scope (i.e., it does not raise an error when passed to a function expecting a different specialized type of self than what mypy reveals).  In contrast, it does enforce type correctness when used in the caller's scope (where it is the object name, not self, but still the same entity of course).  It also enforces it when using a directly typed self instead of a generic.

Below is the mypy playground snippet.  Anyone know what's going on here?

---

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Type

T = TypeVar("T", covariant=True)
TShape = TypeVar("TShape", bound="Shape")

class Shape(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, scale: T) -> None:
        self.scale = scale
        
    def make_circle(self: Shape[str], radius: float) -> Circle:
        return Circle(self, radius)
        
    def make_circle2(self: TShape, radius: float) -> Circle:
        return Circle(self, radius)
        
    def make_circle3(self: Shape[object], radius: float) -> Circle:
        # Just checking if mypy raises a type error 
        # in the method's scope when passing a bad Shape[T]
        # to Circle, in case it routinely did not type check self 
        # for some reason.
        # error: Argument 1 to "Circle" has incompatible type "Shape[object]"; expected "Shape[str]"  [arg-type]
        return Circle(self, radius)
        
    def get_self(self: TShape) -> Type[TShape]:
        return type(self)
        

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, shape: Shape[str], radius: float):
        self.radius = radius
        self.scale = float(shape.scale)
        

# Make a Shape[int] instance
a = Shape(5)  # __main__.Shape[builtins.int]

# This is the type error we expect for b2 (why is it 'misc' and not 'arg-type' though?)
b = a.make_circle(5)  # error: Invalid self argument "Shape[int]" to attribute function "make_circle" with type "Callable[[Shape[str], float], Circle]"  [misc]

# Expected the same error as above for b
b2 = a.make_circle2(5)  # ok: __main__.Circle

# Verifies mypy knew TShape was Shape[int], but allowed Circle(self, radius) to pass
c = a.get_self()  # Type[__main__.Shape[builtins.int]]

# Similar type error when invoking with the object 'a' instead of 'self'
d = Circle(a, 5)  # error: Argument 1 to "Circle" has incompatible type "Shape[int]"; expected "Shape[str]"  [arg-type]

# And just to confirm everything works with Shape[str]
a2 = Shape("5") # __main__.Shape[builtins.str]
a2.make_circle(5) # ok
a2.make_circle2(5)  # ok
Circle(a2, 5) # ok

a.make_circle3(5)

reveal_locals()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see the point of being able to create a shapeless `Shape` to be used to construct an instance of a subclass, instead of simply calling something like `Circle(scale=..., radius=...)`.

Comment: `Shape[T]` IRL is like `Node[T, U]` connected to other nodes up and downstream: `n1` receives type `T` and emits type `U` so its upstream is `[Any, T]` and its downstream is `[U, Any]`.  We want to chain to create new nodes like `m = Node[Any, float]().map(func).window(10).mean()` and for nodes specialized in their types we want the type checker to emit an error if the upstream node is incompatible.  E.g., `m: Mean[Sequence[SupportsFloat], float]` and so when `self: Window[T, U]` is passed to the bound method `mean()` it should not type unless `U <: Sequence[SupportsFloat]`.  Hope that's clear

Comment: It might be better to rework your question to include something closer to your actual use case. (The first thing I notice about your example is that `Node` doesn't take any (explicit?) arguments, so it doesn't seem to need to be generic in the first place: `map` is the first thing that can take a non-generic node and add some type-specific behavior by way of `func`.)